# Android kotlin debugging coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Before coroutines I used callbacks and debugging always gave me a lot of information. I could get the url my API call is going to, Headers I put into Request, interceptors I used, etc..

Now I use coroutines. All I can get when debugging is the final result of request (fail/sucess) with the result data. Nothing of all these valuable info I need is not there.

shortened example of my code:

```
 restService.getVersionInfo().getResult(
            success = {
                when {
                    checkIsMandatory(it.lastMandatoryVersion) -> status.postValue(
                        Status.NewVersionInfo(it.description, true, it.url)
                    )

                    else -> initialization()
                }
            },
            error = {
                initialization()
            }
```

I pout breakpoints to error or sucess. Am I missing something or coroutines really have this disadvantage. Please inform me

Comment: Hey! I think inside getResult method you can see these details. But if you are changing from callback to high order functions or threads to coroutines. It will give you the same logs and information that you need.

Comment: `Before coroutines I used callbacks` a callback doesn't really do the same thing as a coroutine, does it? i'm intrigued by how you used callbacks to achieve what a coroutine does

Comment: @a_local_nobody Since coroutines use those callbacks in their implementation, I can pretty clearly see what OP means.

Comment: ahh i think i understand , thanks @MarkoTopolnik

Comment: I don't think it's anything specific to coroutines, but to the way you map the callback API to suspendable functions. They tend to be implemented to give the most convenience to the common case, but a good library will also have a way to get the whole result object back. You can also implement your own suspendable functions directly on top of the original async API and tailor them to your needs and tastes.